# Reset Boundary-reaching Variables in a Loop

Tags: php, loops, pixel, rgba

So, essentially I'm looping over a large array stored in `$pixels`. In the for loop, there are to be 2 variables, `$x` and `$y`. Variable `$x` needs to increase on each loop until it reaches a predefined boundary, `$xBound`, after which it resets to Zero. Variable `$y` needs to increase if and when $x resets until it reaches its own boundary, `$yBound`. When the boundary for $y is reached, the (large) array loop should be finished.

Do any of you know how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
for ($y=0; $y < $yBound; $y++) {  
    for ($x=0; $x < $xBound; $x++) {
        // do whatever here, $pixels[$x][$y]
    }
}
```